# How to store the value of telerik GridTemplateColumn in a JS variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I am working on ASP.NET webforms. I am using Telerik `GridTemplate` to display the data from array.

I have inline `c#` code to manupulate the data and I want to store that data to `js` variable.

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Doc Number">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# (Container.ItemIndex + (DGResult.CurrentPageIndex * DGResult.PageSize) + 1).ToString() %>
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks in advance.